# Updating or Removing a JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, delete-file

I am creating a Phonegap app which loads in information from vimeo using JSONp. I want to know if there is a way of creating a button that updates the feed either live or when a button is clicked. I have research all over for this answer but are yet to find an answer

I have be able to create a button that just runs the JSON request again, but this leads to there being duplicates of the JSON file in the DOM. So this leads me to my next question which is, is there a way to delete/remove an unwanted JSON file? This way I could add the new one and remove the old, hey presto JSON refreshed.

```
$('#jqt .info').click(function() {
    refreshJSON();
});

function refreshJSON() {

//Vimeo .GET
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/album/1751209/videos.json?callback=?',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data){
        gotMeSomeJSON(data);
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('Sorry unable to download data. You need a good wifi connection to run this app.');
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there away of modifying this code to remove/replace the .json file? http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss2.shtml

Answer (score 1):

In principle, to remove a js reference all you need to do is target it and use  remove child, something like this for example:

```
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; //target the right one

s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
```